# Is there a name for the smallest $c$ so that $c\cdot P$ is an integral polytope?

Tags: terminology, polytopes

Let $P$ be a polytope in $\Bbb Q^d$ and let $c$ be the smallest positive integer so that $c\cdot P$ has vertices in $\Bbb Z^d$.

Is there standard vocabulary to refer to $c$? Something like the *integral index* of $P$ makes sense, but I haven't seen terms like this used before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct quote from "The minimum period of the Ehrhart quasi-polynomial of a rational polytope" by Tyrrell B. McAllister and Kevin M. Woods:

Given a rational polytope $P \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$, the denominator of $P$ is
$$\mathcal{D}(P)=\min \left\{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}: n P \text { is an integral polytope }\right\}.$$